# How to retrieve lost calendar data?

Tags: restore, calendar

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S23 Ultra. I've lost all the data on my calendar. I manually typed everything in the calendar that came on the phone. I don't use the Google Calendar app, but I've noticed the calendar pulls in events from my Gmail.

Last night, I was trying to figure out why the battery of my phone was suddenly not lasting all day even though my usage patterns haven't changed. After reading a few articles about T-Mobile adding apps during updates, I disabled and deleted a few. For example, I disabled configAPK and deleted a few Meta ones.  I googled what each were beforehand. None said anything about the calendar. I'm guessing I've messed up.

Is there any way to get my calendar back, restore the calendar to yesterday, or restore my phone to yesterday? I'm ok to lose what I've done on my phone in the last 24 hours.

I checked my backups. Looks like the last backup was Jan 28. So backing up to a previous date won't work. The invites my husband accepted are still on his phone. If the invite is still on his phone, doesn't that mean the calendar is there somewhere?

Comment: Usually calendars are Google calendars so they are automatically synced with your Google account. If you are logged in with Google in your web browser you can check your calendar(s) at https://calendar.google.com.

Comment: @Robert I would give you a hug if I could. It's all there!!!

Comment: Then you only have to re-enable the apps required to provide and sync the calendar on your device. For safety I would export your calendar, just to make sure https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37111?hl=en

Comment: As Robert was probably thinking, you'll want to create that calendar export right away from calendar.google.com before syncing any devices.  By doing so, you know you have a backup if something goes amiss during the sync process.

Comment: Robert and @End Anti-Semitic Hate Thank you! I'll do that before any other steps.